# Elasticsearch did not update all the fields of a object

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

We have a object stored in Elasticsearch. We create a bulk request with index operations on all our new/to be updated objects. We have observed that some of the field values are not updated. Even after 2 days we are seeing old data in that particular field

E.g. We have a status field and a reason field, which denotes the status of the object and reason of the status. Say initially status field was set to 'first' and stored in the elastic index. Next when an update happens to the field and the status value is changed to 'second' and sent to elastic search, this updated value is not being shown while retrieving the result. The reason field was correctly updated but not the status field. I thought elastic search will update either entire document or none. But in this case only some fields were updated

What could possible reasons be for this partial update ? Our elastic version is 5.1

Note: This is happening Transiently